# grep : how to color 2 keywords?

Tags: grep

I know how to grep 2 keywords using 1 command, but I can only manage to color one of them in output . Here is my command:

```
grep 'keyword1' file.log | grep 'keyword2'
```

Only `keyword2` is highlighted. How can I make `keyword1` highlighted at the same time ?

Answer (score 16):

The `grep` command accepts a `--color=always` option, so you can use

```
grep 'keyword1' file.log --color=always | grep 'keyword2'
```

As [gertvdijk points out](https://askubuntu.com/a/234545/72363), this command may be inefficient, but it will look for all lines that contain both keyword1 and keyword2. If you want to highlight them in different colors, you can use

```
grep 'keyword1' file.log --color=always | GREP_COLORS="mt=01;34" grep --color=always 'keyword2'
```

which will highlight keyword2 in blue. The `mt` part means that `grep` will highlight matching text using this [CSI code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes), and `01;34` means "bold blue foreground on normal background".

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation and customization options for the use case!

Comment: Funny, when I try this with: grep -R --color=always keyword1. | grep keyword2  //only the first keyword is higlighted. How could I adapt your answer to work with recursive search?

Comment: That's odd, `grep -R --color=always keyword1 . | grep keyword2` should work. Are you redirecting the output again (such as by piping the second `grep` into `less -R`)? If so, you'll need to add `--color=always` to the second one also.

Comment: Great answer! To highlight both, a `--color=auto` would be needed for the second `grep`, just after `'keyword2'`.

Comment: @Luis Yeah, you’re right that Grep at least often defaults to no color (although that might be a configure-time option? I don’t think I had that overridden in 2013 when it worked on my machine without that…). I added `--color=always` to the answer, because you might want to pipe it to `less` or something also.

Comment: @DanielH I hadn't thought on piping to `less`, but I just tried and, for some reason, it messes up the format, with `ESC` codes and things o_O Anyway, thank you for updating the answer!

Comment: @Luis Yeah, by default `less` doesn't interpret escape codes. You need to pass `-R` to get it to do that.

Comment: @DanielH Yep, found that too :) Thanks again!!

Answer (score 4):

Try actual regular expressions, rather than piping to another instance of `grep`, e.g.:

```
grep -E "\<foo\>.*\<bar\>" file
```

This limits to matching lines in which this the keywords match in this order only, unfortunately. Anyway, the use of `grep` in your question is rather inefficient and you should avoid it. The [answer of @DanielH](https://askubuntu.com/a/234547/88802) is pretty much more straightforward for your case, probably.

For an 'or' matching of keywords, I use this regularly:

```
grep -E "(foo|bar)" file
```

Comment: I think that the OP wants only lines that contain both keywords (the command you gave gives all lines that contain either one).

Comment: @DanielH Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Doesn't that still only work if foo comes before bar? I don't know if there's a better way than `foo.*bar|bar.*foo`, or if that is even necessary for this case (which appears to be a log file which would probably have a standard order for the keywords). I added my answer before you updated yours, but I'll keep it around in case there's a situation where chained `grep`s really are necessary (or any other time colored output shouldn't be sent to the terminal, like `grep | less -R`).